# How to use webpack to bundle typescript library to js script

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I wrote a simple typescript library, which I use as a npm library. It looks like that:

**index.ts**

```
import * as peselManager from './pesel';

/**
 * Returns information if PESEL number is valid.
 *
 * @param {string} pesel
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
export const isValidPesel = (pesel: string): boolean => {
    return peselManager.isValid(pesel);
};
```

Everything is fine, but i would like to use my library as js script too. For this I used webpack, with fallowing configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./lib/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "peseljs.min.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin()
    ]
};
```

When I use `webpack` command I got minify js script. But when I add this script to example page like that:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>PeselJS Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="PeselJS Example Page">
    <meta name="author" content="jaroslawkrol">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="peseljs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="some-span">ABC</span>
<script>
    var isValid = isValidPesel("22032101355");
    if(isValid) {
        console.log("valid");
    } else {
        console.log("invalid");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I got error about `Uncaught ReferenceError: isValidPesel is not defined`. **And my question:** Is there a way to bundle my library to call a function like this? Is it a good practise? Maybe, I did it totally wrong, so I will be happy to hear your comments.

Comment: Please refer https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/ link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use your exported function as if it has been attached to the global scope. With webpack defaults this is not the case, all your code will be wrapped in closures that the global scope has no access to, unless you configure webpack to actually expose your top level exports

To do this use the `library` config option https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library

```
output: {
    filename: "peseljs.min.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'myLibraryName'
}
```

This will assign the entry module to a variable (which will exist in whatever scope the webpack lib is loaded into - in your case `window`), that in turn references anything you export from your entry file, allowing you to call your function through it

```
const isValid = myLibraryName.isValidPesel("22032101355")
```

If you need finer control of what scope this library variable is placed into there are further library options to allow this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget